# Python: parsing files separated by tabs and spaces

Tags: python-2.7, text-parsing

I have some files to parse which are poorly formatted. One of the issues I face is that the fields in the file are separated by spaces, tabs or spaces & tabs.

Could someone explain how I can replace the tabs with spaces so that I can split the fields of each line into a list?

Comment: [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without giving a separator splits on tab and/or space. What prevents you from just using that? :)

Comment: That appears to work for the variation I'm testing right now - I thought it only split on spaces (my bad). I'll check the docs more throughly next time. I have another line variant that might not work with this but I'll test that later.